# What is a good book to learn AP Physics C?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, resource-recommendations

I am looking to learn AP Physics C (if you are not acquainted with the curriculum see [here](http://secure-media.collegeboard.org/digitalServices/pdf/ap/ap-physics-c-course-description.pdf)), both the mechanics part *and* the electricity/magnetism part. I have not had much exposure to an AP-style physics curriculum for AP Physics 1 or 2 (before C). Ideally this book would be some sort of AP-preparation book, but I am not taking a course and most of the books I have seen which are designed as "AP-prep" are meant to be supplements to an actual course. Ideally this book would also be comprehensive, easy to follow, and it would explain the intuition (if there is any) behind concepts. A book which I found to be the *perfect* example of this (at least for me) was Morris Tenenbaum's and Henry Pollard's book, *Ordinary Differential Equations* (maybe you have read it).

Comment: AP Physics C covers Newtonian mechanics and electromagnetism (right?), but I couldn't choose more than one duplicate. The point is, I don't think being specific to an AP course is enough justification to have a separate question asking about introductory physics books.

Answer (score 0):

When I was in high school about 7 years ago, I taught myself a lot of what was necessary to get a 5 on both the AP Physics B and C exams through Dr. James Mooney's AP test preparation books.  I would recommend these for learning physics at the high school level, especially if you are trying to learn quickly and well in preparation for the AP test. These books have good explanations for many of the questions in the back.

Answer (score 0):

I have to suggest [Barron's AP Physics C](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0764147072) supplemented by [some lectures from Professor Walter Lewin](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCliSRiiRVQuDfgxI_QN_Fmw). Though designed as a supplement, the Barron books are fairly good at getting you right to the heart of the physics, complete with proofs when appropriate. It's also got a great set of practice problems.